# Is there any 64-bit PDF plugin for browsers?

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, browser, pdf-reader

I'm now using a 64-bit version of a browser based on Firefox' rendering engine, but I don't see PDFs inside the browser because all of the readers I found are 32-bit, so their plugins don't work.

Is there any PDF reader that provides a 64-bit browser plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [PDF X-Change Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer).

They offer a 64-bit version.

Comment: A link would be handy because it does not seem to be listed in the Chrome web-store.

Answer (score 1):

I like [SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) and although there is no official 64-bit version there are some unofficial builds which provide a 64-bit browser plugin.

Check [here](http://xhmikosr.1f0.de/sumatrapdf/) for unstable builds and [here](http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?SumatraPDF) for both stable and unstable ones.

Comment: Thank you, I prefer the other one though because it's officially supported.

Comment: The x64 version of Sumatra PDF doesn't seem to install a browser plug-in for Chrome x64.